# AAPT2 error in project module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt2

My project contains two modules namely admin and user.
The user module works without any error however the admin module throws compile time error as follows:

```
error: style attribute '@android:attr/attr/gravity' not found.
error: style attribute 'attr/@attr/minTextSize (aka com.ict.school.admin:attr/@attr/minTextSize)' not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    first 
     in gradle.properties add code below
    android.enableAapt2=false


    second:
    A new version of Gradle and Android-gradle-plugin is available that fixes these issues.
add this in app geadle:

    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
        }
    }

and after that in gradle-wrapper.properties change distributionUrl:

    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

On "gradle-wrapper.properties" use the latest version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip
```

And on your "build.gradle" app file the same, the latest version:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha03'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
```

I've been several hours looking for a solution to this AAPT2 Error after upgrading Android Studio to the  3.1.3 version. It solved the issue.